# Bug de caracteres estranhos na UI do Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: O programa apresentou este problema e mesmo após a reinstalação o bug persiste.]

Alguém já presenciou algum problema parecido?

Comment: Creio que você pode ter instalado-o com uma linguagem diferente. Já tentou mexer nas configurações? Vocês o baixou da página oficial da Google?

Comment: Com certeza baixou ou instalou em algum idioma o qual você não tem o pacote de idiomas instalado nessa maquina, então alguns caracteres especiais desse idioma ficam "bugados" assim.

Comment: Acredito que de pra mudar o idioma ao lado da engrenagem dentada, tente isso.